Flutter special character rendering problem with GoogleFonts
When I use GoogleFonts some special characters not shown correctly.


I tried to use it with default font family but it doesn't work either.
Text( data["pronunciation"], style: TextStyle( color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 12, fontFamily: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontFamily )

